# Pandas: why Series.value_counts() returns counts with zero?

Tags: pandas

The command `df.col.value_counts()` is returning attributes with zero instances counted. This is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of columns of type `category`, as you can see in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/categorical.html#operations) and in this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8559). It really behaves differently than other types. It is very useful if you have charts that you must show zero for categories that aren't present.

To change this behavior, the solution is very simple, convert the column back to string:

```
df.col.astype('str').value_counts()
```